# Commenting out Content - HTML and PHP

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce, comments

I am currently tweaking a BigCommerce theme for my employer. They have asked me to remove and change a few CSS / HTML elements to fit the style and functionality that they are after.

Rather than just DELETING the functionality within the theme, I was hoping to just comment it out in case it is needed later. But I am having an issue with the formatting.

The following is the code as displayed in the ProductDetails.html Panel file:

```
    <div class="Content" id="prodAccordion">
        %%Panel.ProductTabs%%
        %%Panel.ProductDescription%%
        %%Panel.ProductVideos%%
        %%Panel.ProductWarranty%%
        %%Panel.ProductOtherDetails%%
        %%Panel.SimilarProductsByTag%%
        %%Panel.ProductReviews%%
        %%Panel.ProductByCategory%%
        %%Panel.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews%%
    </div>
```

I am trying to comment out the last 3 lines only.

However, when I do, the end of the comment ( --> ) shows up in the browser. I have closed the comments correctly but there must be some simple concept that I am missing. Hoping the good people at SO can help.

Below is the code as I have saved it and a screenshot of the display in my browser. The first screen shot is how it looks before I add any comments and the second is after I add them. You can clearly see the closing comment in the second image, can anyone tell me why??

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    <div class="Content" id="prodAccordion">
        %%Panel.ProductTabs%%
        %%Panel.ProductDescription%%
        %%Panel.ProductVideos%%
        %%Panel.ProductWarranty%%
        %%Panel.ProductOtherDetails%%
        %%Panel.SimilarProductsByTag%%
        <!--%%Panel.ProductReviews%%-->
        <!--%%Panel.ProductByCategory%%-->
        <!--%%Panel.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews%%-->
    </div>
```

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Sure you don't have a commented out section somewhere else in the code?  Maybe do a find/replace on that file?  What you have above is just fine.

Comment: What if to leave a space there? i.e. `<!-- %%Panel.ProductReviews%% -->`

Comment: Have you tried using just one tag for all three lines? Like  

<!-- %%Panel.ProductReviews%%
        %%Panel.ProductByCategory%%
       %%Panel.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews%% -->

Comment: Sean - Just had a find and replace trawl through that panel of code - everything else seems ok - all opened, closed and displaying (or not displaying!) as they should.

Comment: sdcr - I did try that but it didn't make a difference. I tried again in case but to no avail.

Comment: James - I did, and I just tried again but nothing new - the end characters of the comment still show. The really weird thing is that if I comment out the first line, the characters don't show - but if I comment out the second or third, they do.

Comment: Did you look through the code in your browser? There may be a comment in the code outputted by `Panel.ProductByCategory` and/or `Panel.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews`

Comment: @Greg - Thank you! I looked at both panel files that you mentioned and they did contain comments. They were opened and closed correctly but once I removed them, the characters stopped showing in the browser! I am not entirely sure I understand what has happened here as I would have assumed a comment that was opened and closed correctly in one section wouldn't do that to another but I obviously have a lot to learn within Big Commerce.

Comment: Even though they were closed correctly in the panel files, your parent comment that commented out the ProductByCategory and SimilarProductsByCustomerViews was being ended by the `-->` found inside those files. Therefore, your parent closing `-->` tag had no start tag, and was showing up :)

Comment: You could also [comment out this section using PHP](https://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php), so those bits aren't visible to the client. In this case it doesn't matter too much, but it's generally a good practice - your page size is ever so slightly smaller and, more importantly, you don't risk revealing any sensitive information. i.e. `<?# We're stuck doing X because we're using PHP 4.X.X, which is known to be susceptible to exploits X, Y and Z. ?>`

Comment: To further explain what @AlexWright said, you could demonstrate your problem with code that looks like this: `<!-- left <!-- inner --> right -->`. The browser would start the comment at the first `<!--` and go until the first `-->`, meaning the contents of the comment would be `<!-- left <!-- inner -->` and ` right -->` would not be a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicole, I've dealt with this and can definitely explain **why** it's happening and **how** to avoid it.

### Why It's Happening

It's happening because this is how BigCommerce's server side PHP processor parses the code you're looking at.  The code is basic HTML, while the %%Panel.something%% are simply ways for BigCommerce's processor to recognize as a command for BigCommerce.
Anytime the BC site sees %%Panel.Name%%, it knows that this is not HTML, but rather a place where BC server-side processor should insert the Panel file before serving this HTML to the user.

### How to Avoid it and Comment-out Correctly

Simply, remove the % symbols and use regular commenting. This will work:

```
 <!-- Panel.ProductReviews-->
```

So will this:

```
 <!--%%Panel.ProductReviews-->
```

And this:

```
  <!-- Panel.ProductReviews%%-->
```

Or even this:

```
  <!-- %Panel.ProductReviews% -->
```

Mainly, you have to make sure that each side of a `Panel.Name` reference, *doesn't have 2 % symbols on each side*.

### To Restore the Correctly Commented Out Code/Panel

Simply restore the 2 `%` symbols on each side like so (the spaces between `-` and `%` don't matter, you can have none or 10):

```
  <!-- %%Panel.ProductReviews%% -->
```

---

### Why You're Seeing `-->` On Live Site

As broached/explained in the comments of your question, you're seeing `-->` when commenting out a Panel like so `<!--%%Panel.Name%%-->` because by commenting out the Panel that way without removing at least one of the `%` symbols, you're still telling BigCommerce to load the Panel HTML file, but to place it within the

```
<!-- [HTML code from panel goes here] -->
```

The problem with that is simply that some of these Panel files contain comments themselves. 
For example, let's say you comment out `%%Panel.Header%%` like so `!<--%%Panel.Header%%-->`.   The Header.html Panel may be code like this:

```
<!-- this is the header code panel-->
<div class"MainHeader">
     <ul class="TopNav">
         ...
     </ul>
</div>
```

By commenting out the code without removing the `%` symbols, BigCommerce will load this:

```
<!--
<!-- this is the header code panel-->
<div class"MainHeader">
     <ul class="TopNav">
         ...
     </ul>
</div>
-->
```

when a user open a page that uses the Header.html panel, they will see this code as commented **`<!--`**`<!-- this is the header code panel`**`-->`**, because the browser will start the comment at the first `<!--` and end the comment at the first appearance of `-->`.

In the browser, the user will see the uncommented remains:

```
<div class"MainHeader">
     <ul class="TopNav">
         ...
     </ul>
</div>
-->
```

And hence you'll see some extra, probably broken HTML, plus the stray `-->` somewhere at the end of the improperly commented code.

Again, to avoid all this, just remove one of the `%` symbols, then use regular commenting to comment out a Panel file reference.

Let me know if this helps and if you have any other questions.